# Error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" in VSCode

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, spring-tool-suite

When I tried "Create Maven Project" in VSCode, the following Error message showed up.

---

```
> Executing task: "c:\Users\devin\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.30.0\resources\maven-wrapper\mvnw.cmd" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="spring-boot-blank-archetype" -DarchetypeGroupId="am.ik.archetype" -DarchetypeVersion="1.0.0" -DgroupId="io.javabrains.springbootquickstart" -DartifactId="course-api" -DoutputDirectory="d:\Projects\Springboot" <

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The terminal process "cmd.exe /c "c:\Users\devin\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-maven-0.30.0\resources\maven-wrapper\mvnw.cmd" org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId="spring-boot-blank-archetype" -DarchetypeGroupId="am.ik.archetype" -DarchetypeVersion="1.0.0" -DgroupId="io.javabrains.springbootquickstart" -DartifactId="course-api" -DoutputDirectory="d:\Projects\Springboot"" failed to launch (exit code: 1).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

---

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but did you try the Spring Boot Initializr extension to create new Spring Boot projects in VSCode? It provides a nice integration for https://start.spring.io into VS Code and I wonder whether that would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error you've encountered should be related to [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Please try the following ways to create maven project:

1. Use the extension **Spring Initializer Java Support** to [create project](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot#_create-the-project)
2. Add Maven to Path and follow the tutorial [create maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

Please try again and see if the error goes away.